# Max parameter size for NSData / setHTTPBody?

Tags: ios, iis-7, http-post, nsdata, maxrequestlength

My iPad app sends a list of files as a string parameter, `fileList` to a web method like this:

```
NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"sessionID=%@&fileList=%@&dateTime=%@&userID=%@", sessionID, fileList, timeOpened, userID];    
NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
NSString *comparisonURLString = SERVER_COMPARE_URL_STRING;
NSURL *comparisonURL = [NSURL URLWithString:comparisonURLString];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:comparisonURL];

NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request addValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];
```

When the list of files is above a certain size, it seems to be truncated. I couldn't find anything about a maximum size in [the apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html). Also, the subsequent parameters seem to be received OK regardless but before I discount this as a possible source of the problem, I was wondering if anyone knows if there is such a limitation?

The server is running IIS7, and the webConfig `maxRequestLength` is set to 1048576.

-EDIT-

**Source of the Problem:**

I created a webmethod that only takes in the entire `POST` as a parameter and it removes everything after an ampersand (&) so I think this may be where the problem lies, rather than parameter size.

Comment: u want to send req. by POST method ??

Comment: Are you setting the `Content-Length` HTTP request header?

Comment: @trojanfoe: Yes, sorry. I've edited to question to include that code.

Comment: I don't see where `postLength` is created.  Also are you setting the `Content-Type` HTTP request header?

Comment: I've added that `postLength` line but I don't have anything for `Content-Type`. I didn't realise I needed to set that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I *think* the issue might be a missing `Content-Type` HTTP Request header field:

```
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
```

Also use UTF-8 to encode the payload:

```
NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
```

Comment: OK, then time to turn to the server.  Are you able to *mimic* your POST request using some other technology in order to verify that the problem doesn't lie within the server?

Comment: I'm able to enter the individual parameters locally on the server, although not the whole POST request.

Comment: You need to mimic the POST request elsewhere in order to rule-out a server issue.  You might be barking up the wrong tree.

Comment: I created a webmethod that only takes in the entire `POST` as a parameter and it removes everything after an ampersand (&) so I think this may be where the problem lies, rather than parameter size.

Comment: I was indeed barking up the wrong tree. Some of the document titles contained ampersands. I wrote a little routine to change them to `and` on upload and that seems to have solved it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Robert Another approach is to run all your parameters through `[NSString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:]` before adding them to the payload.